# draw a line in matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am new in matlab tool. i want to draw many lines in my GUI in matlab. standard tools in matlab haven't a control like shape or line and so on.

my UI include the other controls like push button and static text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot use the `line()` command, to draw directly on the figure. However, there is a trick: You can make an invisible axis because the visibility does not propagate to the children. Drawing on an invisible axis, is nearly as good as drawing on the figure directly. Here is an example:

```
f = figure;
a = axes;
set(a, 'Visible', 'off');
%# Stretch the axes over the whole figure.
set(a, 'Position', [0, 0, 1, 1]);
%# Switch off autoscaling.
set(a, 'Xlim', [0, 1], 'YLim', [0, 1]);

%# Create all the controls.
uicontrol('Parent', f, 'Style', 'edit', 'String', 'Input...');

%# Draw!
for y = 1 : 9
    line([0.1, 1], [1 - y/10, 0.5], 'Parent', a)
end
```

**Edit:** Of course, it is a good idea to disable the autoscaling of the axes. Otherwise, drawing is much less predictable.

Comment: thanks Mehrwolf, when i use above code, at run, opening two window, the my UI an a window with "Figure 1" name. i think i must change figure(1);

Comment: @hamedajorloo: Yes you are correct. `figure(1)` will bring the figure no. 1 on top. I changed this in the code.